# I would like to loop through an array looking for the first value that does not match 2345 string

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, loops, foreach

I am going to rephrase my question so people understand what I am trying to achieve which will make it easier to help me.
I have several objects `objInputMessage` which are found in `objInputMessages`.

Also the object after the first one is what I am considering the first `strMessageCaseNumber`.

The reason is that the `strMessageCaseNumber` in the first object happens to be the newest and I want to find the older `strMessageCaseNumber` that was prior to the changed one (new).

In my case the changed `strMessageCaseNumber` is 2345 so I would like to get the previous one before the change which is 2346
These objects `objInputMessage` each contains `strMessageCaseNumber` variable.

For example the object `objInputMessage` has `strMessageCaseNumber` with a value 2345. This is the `strMessageCaseNumber` (2345) that I want to compare with the next object's `strMessageCaseNumber`.

If the next (first) object's `strMessageCaseNumber` (in my case 2346) does not match `strMessageCaseNumber` 2345, then I want to assign that value to a variable I named `strPriorCaseNumber`

So the end result would be `strPriorCaseNumber' =`strMessageCaseNumber`

and the `strPriorCaseNumber' will contain **2346**

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a For Each, but it is probably easier to use a Linq query:

Setup some data to use:

```
    Dim values As String() = {"2345", "2346", "236", "2347"}
```

Find the first non-matching value:

```
    Dim foundValue = values.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x <> "2345")
    If foundValue IsNot Nothing Then MessageBox.Show(foundValue)
```

For completeness the equivalent For Each would look something like this:

```
    For Each value In values
        If value <> "2345" Then
            MessageBox.Show(value)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: `First` will throw an exception if "2345" is not found. I think you meant `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: @Blackwood - well actually the exception is thrown if the only element in the array is "2345" but yes you have a valid point